# Is Post-Author-Id shortocde

Tags: shortcode

How difficult would it be to create a shortcode based on the following code:

```
<?php if($post->post_author == '8'): ?>
Yes This Post Is By Author Id 8
<?php endif; ?>
```

The shortcode then would be something like [post author="8"] Text Here [/post-author]

I am ok with creating simple shortcodes but when it gets to using parameters I get a little lost.

Comment: Not at all. Did you try something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward as far as [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) go:

```
function wpse_226998_post_author( $atts, $text ) {
    if ( ! empty( $atts['id'] ) && $atts['id'] == get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) )
        return $text;
}

add_shortcode( 'post_author', 'wpse_226998_post_author' );
```

And in practice:

```
[post_author id="8"]This post is by author ID 8[/post_author]
```